# C++ application causing Windows Handle leakage using multiple TClientSocket instances

Tags: c++, c++builder-xe2, tthread, tclientsocket

I have come across an apparent handle leakage using the Borland/Embarcadero `TClientSocket` component. I have an application that creates multiple `TThread` instances, each of which creates a `TClientSocket` object dynamically, connects to its target sends a few messages and then is deleted. The `TThread` instances are then deleted (using the `FreeOnTerminate = true`) setting. I know that this is inefficient, but it suits the needs of the application perfectly - the maximum number of `TThread` instances capable of existing simultaneously are limited to 32. The problem I am seeing is that there is a clear windows Handle leakage problem that I can see via Task Manager. In an attempt to isolate the problem I applied the same problem in a single threaded sense, just dynamically creating a `TClientSocket` object and deleting it again when finished with within a single loop in the main VCL thread. This exhibits the same handle leakage problem. I know the component is deprecated and I know that what I am doing is inefficient, but I cannot see why there would be a handle leak. Is there anything that needs to be done with the `TClientSocket` objects prior to their deletion to remove this handle leak, or is this a bug in the component? I am using the socket in non blocking mode and assigning event handlers to `OnConnect` `OnDisconnect` and `OnSocketError`.

Comment: SO_LINGER perhaps? Just guessing here. I would be surprised if that was it, as it would be unexpected, but worth a short if you can get that granular control on the underlying socket.

Comment: @WhozCraig: `SO_LINGER` has nothing to do with handles. But yes, it is possible to gain access to the underlying `SOCKET` handle used by `TClientSocket` (via the `TClientSocket.Socket.SocketHandle` property) and directly call WinSock API functions on it, like `setsockopt()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is there not an IO handle behind that socket? I.e, if I open 10,000 sockets and fire up procexp i'm *not* going to see the handle-count proportionate? I only brought it up because I had a similar issue with a high-volume quick-detach app and that was precisely the issue. after the disconnects, without killing the linger timer the handles were not immediately returned. As I said though, I defer to the more knowledgable, which looks like its you. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The `SOCKET` handle itself is closed immediately, but the network resources behind it are not closed immediately if `SO_LINGER` is enabled. That is not a handle leak, that is intentional behavior on the OS side. Those resources will be closed by the OS after a few minutes. But yes, if you have high traffic activity, you can exhaust network resources before they get released, so disabling `SO_LINGER` does help, as long as you understand the consequences of doing so (`SO_LINGER` exists for a reason, after all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `TClientSocket` for many years, including usages in the main thread and in worker thread, and I have never seen `TClientSocket` leak any handles.

However, `TClientSocket` does default to non-blocking mode, and in that mode it uses `AllocateHWnd()` to create a hidden window to receive socket events, and `AllocateHWnd()` is **not thread-safe**.  Without seeing your actual code, that is the likely cause of the leaks you are seeing in your worker thread code.  The solution to that is simply to not use `TClientSocket` is non-blocking mode when used in a worker thread.  Use it in blocking mode instead.  Which lends itself better to thread-based logic anyway.

However, that does not explain the leaks you are seeing in your main thread code.  I doubt `TClientSocket` is actually the culprit, and again, without seeing your actual code, it is hard to say for sure.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I just took a look at the Embarcadero documentation for `AllocateHWnd()` - based on what you say then that also implies that it is unsafe to make use of `TTimer` objects within threads also?

Comment: @mathematician1975: yes, `TTimer` does use `AllocateHWnd()`, so `TTimer` is not safe to use in worker threads as well.  But there are better alternatives for threaded timers, such as `CreateWaitableTimer()`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I will just rewrite everything to use blocking client.